# Buiding GCC, Make failure

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am building gcc-5 and getting the following make problem

```
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/cdi/Local    
         /gcc-release/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
         /32/libjava/classpath'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/cdi/Local/gcc-release
         /objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava'
make[3]: *** [multi-do] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/cdi/Local/gcc-release
         /objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[2]: *** [all-multi] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cdi/Local/gcc-release
         /objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libjava] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cdi/Local/gcc-release
         /objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I investigated if there is a more descriptive make error at an earlier stage, however, I did not find anything.

Comment: The bit you posted here is entirely unhelpful. The lines above this may not have seemed helpful to you but you should include them anyway.

Comment: It is a long listing, what would you need?

Comment: I captured the problem now /home/cdi/Local/gcc-release/gcc-5-20150201/missing: 81: /home/cdi/Local/gcc-release/gcc-5-20150201/missing: makeinfo: not found
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want t

Comment: Sounds like you need to install `makeinfo` then.

Comment: It happens to be Texinfo. I am building again and see what happens.